# How to view my comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments

I got the "Pundit" badge just now. No idea for what exactly.

So I thought it'd be useful if we could view our comments, perhaps a top-ten kind of thing to see the highest ranked. Or at least for the Pundit, allow users to see what comments triggered it.

Comment: See profile -> activity -> comments; there's also [this data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/49864/my-comments-ordered-by-score-pundit-badge-progress)

Comment: I think it would be nice to see how many votes each comment has as well.

Answer (score 6):

Comments are ephemeral and are treated as second class citizens at Stack Exchange. Users may use a [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/190364/my-comments-ordered-by-score-pundit-badge-progress) to find which comments landed them the Pundit badge. It would be a good-to-have but I don't think that this feature-request will be of much use at large.

Comment: Then perhaps in general, for badges, store info about what exactly was the trigger? I don't really understand how SE works internally, but perhaps this could be possible.

Comment: @MightyPork In general, this information is available for some badges. For example, if you get a Nice Question badge then the 'Achievements' dropdown shows the question on which you got the badge. Similarly on the 'Badges' page, if you click on Nice Question badge it will show the list of questions on which the badge was awarded.

Comment: The answers in this MSE post have information about how to check progress on various badges: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports.