# Why can't I edit my reply to an answer posted on a question I created?

Tags: support, comments

I believe I should be able to edit [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40010540/academic-setting-clarification-of-the-term-standard-input-in-java-and-verifyin#comment67408435_40010825), based on [this Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292238/why-cant-i-edit-my-comment-after-5-minutes-but-can-delete-and-create-a-new-one), which states that such edits can be made for up to five minutes. However, I see no such option:

[image: Example]

I thought it may be my reputation, but the [privileges section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) makes no mention of this.

Can anyone please explain what's happening?

Comment: There should be an edit link after the timestamp like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAIui.png

Comment: Are you sure you were logged in at the point you took the screenshot. If you were, you don't have multiple accounts do you?

Comment: Yes I was logged in, and no I don't have multiple accounts.

Update: I can edit comments perfectly fine on this question. Is it something to do with stackoverflow specifically? Here in META it works as intended, but in SO I really can't see the pencil icon.

Comment: BTW, the linked edit privilege doesn't apply to comments; it only applies to other people's questions and answers (nobody can edit others' comments). The comment privilege is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), but it barely even tells you editing comments is possible. It's possible that it's a corner case bug...

Comment: I have a feeling you have fallen into a trap.  The comment anywhere privilege allows you to well, comment everywhere, and edit those comments in the edit window.  Unfortunately you do not have the privilege yet.  You are allowed to comment on your own posts otherwise you would not be able to answer others comments but the edit part of that exception may have been forgotten about.